# Benchmarking utf8 file read - explanation of the differences

Tags: perl, utf-8, io, encode

Have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.016;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Path::Tiny;
use Encode;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $cnt = 10_000;
my $utf = 'utf8.txt';

my $res = timethese($cnt, {
    'open-UTF-8' => sub {
        open my $fhu, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $utf;
        my $stru = do { local $/; <$fhu>};
        close $fhu;
    },
    'open-utf8' => sub {
        open my $fhu, '<:utf8', $utf;
        my $stru = do { local $/; <$fhu>};
        close $fhu;
    },
    'decode-utf8' => sub {
        open my $fhu, '<', $utf;
        my $stru = decode('utf8', do { local $/; <$fhu>});
        close $fhu;
    },
    'decode-UTF-8' => sub {
        open my $fhu, '<', $utf;
        my $stru = decode('UTF-8', do { local $/; <$fhu>});
        close $fhu;
    },
    'ptiny' => sub {
        my $stru = path($utf)->slurp_utf8;
    },
});
cmpthese $res;
```

the `utf8.txt` (approx 175kb) contains 1000 lines of utf8 encoded/ascii chars, like:

```
9áäčďéěíĺľňóôöőŕřšťúůüűýž ÁÄČĎÉĚÍĹĽŇÓÔÖŐŔŘŠŤÚŮÜŰÝŽ aáäbcčdďeéěfghiíjkľĺmnňoóôöőpqrŕřsštťuúůüűvwxyýzž
```

Running the above, on my notebook gives:

```
Benchmark: timing 10000 iterations of decode-UTF-8, decode-utf8, open-UTF-8, open-utf8, ptiny...
decode-UTF-8: 47 wallclock secs (46.83 usr +  0.87 sys = 47.70 CPU) @ 209.64/s (n=10000)
 decode-utf8: 48 wallclock secs (46.62 usr +  0.90 sys = 47.52 CPU) @ 210.44/s (n=10000)
  open-UTF-8: 60 wallclock secs (57.82 usr +  1.20 sys = 59.02 CPU) @ 169.43/s (n=10000)
   open-utf8:  7 wallclock secs ( 6.57 usr +  0.70 sys =  7.27 CPU) @ 1375.52/s (n=10000)
       ptiny:  7 wallclock secs ( 5.98 usr +  0.52 sys =  6.50 CPU) @ 1538.46/s (n=10000)
               Rate  open-UTF-8 decode-UTF-8 decode-utf8   open-utf8       ptiny
open-UTF-8    169/s          --         -19%        -19%        -88%        -89%
decode-UTF-8  210/s         24%           --         -0%        -85%        -86%
decode-utf8   210/s         24%           0%          --        -85%        -86%
open-utf8    1376/s        712%         556%        554%          --        -11%
ptiny        1538/s        808%         634%        631%         12%          --
```

For me surprising, so the questions:

- first - is something wrong with the above code?

If it is ok,

- why the huge difference between explicit `UTF-8` and relaxed `utf8` but only at the at the IO-layer level (`<:utf8` and `<:encoding(UTF-8)`? So,
- why the difference not so big when `decode('UTF-8'` and `decode('utf8'` ?
- why the lazy - IO-layer level decode is much-much faster as the explicit also lazy `decode('utf8`?
- and what "danger" could be using the relaxed (fast) "utf8' vs exact (slow) 'UTF-8'?
- and finally, not really an question - i must check the Path::Tiny code - how it is the fastest...

Env:

- perl v5.22.0 - perlbrew (threaded)
- OSX -  Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: (yosemite)
- notebook old - MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010) - core-2-duo, 2.4Ghz, 8GB, slow HDD

Comment: Her are my results ( Ubuntu 14.10, Lenovo Edge 540, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4712MQ CPU @ 2.30GHz ) :  http://pastebin.com/kUst2Bim . Input file : http://pastebin.com/7fMnpFLQ

Comment: @HåkonHægland Similar. Also huge diff between lazy/strict `on the layer` and not big diff between lazy/strict `decode`. Surprise the path::tiny.

Comment: @jm666, The reason is probably because Håkon Hægland doesn't have Unicode::UTF8 installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## :utf8

The PerlIO [`:utf8`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO#utf8) layer is a pseudo layer, it's simply a flag on the PerlIO handle which the OP detect. The behavior varies depending on the used OP:

read(), sysread() and recv():

The [implementation](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.23.1/pp_sys.c#L1638) performs no validation of the utf8 sequences. The implementation [only checks the prefix octet](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.23.1/pp_sys.c#L1841) of the utf8 sequence to count the number of read utf8 sequences.

readline():

The [implementation](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.23.1/pp_hot.c#L1572) validates the read octets [if the warnings](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.23.1/pp_hot.c#L1750) category `'utf8'` is in effect and issues a warning if the read octets contains ill-formed utf8. The used validation procedure is the same as used in [`utf8::decode()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/utf8#Utility-functions).

The ':utf8' flag/layer should never be used for reading unless you are willing to accept Ill-formed UTF-X which could lead to [security issues](http://unicode.org/versions/corrigendum1.html) or segmentation faults.

## :encoding

The PerlIO `:encoding` layer is provided by [PerlIO::encoding](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::encoding) which implements an incremental decoder framework for subclasses of [Encode::Encoding](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Encoding). The [implementation](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.22.0/ext/PerlIO-encoding/encoding.xs) calls out to the Perl/XS subclass by invoking a method for each incremental decode. Buffers are copied between the layer and the subclass.

## utf8 vs UTF-8

The utf8 encoding form is a superset of the UTF-8 encoding form specified by the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org) Consortium. The utf8 encoding form accepts encoded code points that are ill-formed in the UTF-8 encoding form, such as [surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) and code points above U+10FFFF. [Non-characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Non-characters) should also be avoided, even though Unicode [recently changed](http://www.unicode.org/versions/corrigendum9.html) their mind. The utf8 encoding should not be used for interchange, it's Perl's internal encoding. Use the UTF-8 encoding form instead.

## Benchmark of slurping UTF-8 encoded file

Modules used in the benchmark:

[PerlIO::encoding](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::encoding), [PerlIO::utf8_strict](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::utf8_strict), [Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) and [Unicode::UTF8](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::UTF8).

The following code is also available on [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/chansen/254a01d69490d93297f4).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark     qw[];
use Config        qw[%Config];
use IO::Dir       qw[];
use IO::File      qw[SEEK_SET];

use Encode              qw[];
use Unicode::UTF8       qw[];
use PerlIO::encoding    qw[];
use PerlIO::utf8_strict qw[];

# https://github.com/chansen/p5-unicode-utf8/tree/master/benchmarks/data
my $dir  = 'benchmarks/data';
my @docs = do {
    my $d = IO::Dir->new($dir)
      or die qq/Could not open directory '$dir': $!/;
    sort grep { /^[a-z]{2}\.txt/ } $d->read;
};

printf "perl:                %s (%s %s)\n", $], @Config{qw[osname osvers]};
printf "Encode:              %s\n", Encode->VERSION;
printf "Unicode::UTF8:       %s\n", Unicode::UTF8->VERSION;
printf "PerlIO::encoding:    %s\n", PerlIO::encoding->VERSION;
printf "PerlIO::utf8_strict: %s\n", PerlIO::utf8_strict->VERSION;

foreach my $doc (@docs) {

    my $octets = do {
        open my $fh, '<:raw', "$dir/$doc" or die $!;
        local $/; <$fh>;
    };

    my $string = Unicode::UTF8::decode_utf8($octets);

    my @ranges = (
        [    0x00,     0x7F, qr/[\x{00}-\x{7F}]/        ],
        [    0x80,    0x7FF, qr/[\x{80}-\x{7FF}]/       ],
        [   0x800,   0xFFFF, qr/[\x{800}-\x{FFFF}]/     ],
        [ 0x10000, 0x10FFFF, qr/[\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]/ ],
    );

    my @out;
    foreach my $r (@ranges) {
        my ($start, $end, $regexp) = @$r;
        my $count = () = $string =~ m/$regexp/g;
        push @out, sprintf "U+%.4X..U+%.4X: %d", $start, $end, $count
          if $count;
    }

    printf "\n\n%s: Size: %d Code points: %d (%s)\n",
      $doc, length $octets, length $string, join ' ', @out;

    open my $fh_raw, '<:raw', \$octets 
      or die qq/Could not open a :raw fh: '$!'/;
    open my $fh_encoding, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', \$octets
      or die qq/Could not open a :encoding fh: '$!'/;
    open my $fh_utf8_strict, '<:utf8_strict', \$octets 
      or die qq/Could not open a :utf8_strict fh: '$!'/;

    Benchmark::cmpthese( -10, {
        ':encoding(UTF-8)' => sub {
            my $data = do { local $/; <$fh_encoding> };
            seek($fh_encoding, 0, SEEK_SET)
              or die qq/Could not rewind fh: '$!'/;
        },
        ':utf8_strict' => sub {
            my $data = do { local $/; <$fh_utf8_strict> };
            seek($fh_utf8_strict, 0, SEEK_SET)
              or die qq/Could not rewind fh: '$!'/;
        },
        'Encode' => sub {
            my $data = Encode::decode('UTF-8', do { local $/; scalar <$fh_raw> }, Encode::FB_CROAK|Encode::LEAVE_SRC);
            seek($fh_raw, 0, SEEK_SET)
             or die qq/Could not rewind fh: '$!'/;
        },        
        'Unicode::UTF8' => sub {
            my $data = Unicode::UTF8::decode_utf8(do { local $/; scalar <$fh_raw> });
            seek($fh_raw, 0, SEEK_SET)
             or die qq/Could not rewind fh: '$!'/;
        },
    });
}
```

Results:

```
$ perl benchmarks/slurp.pl 
perl:                5.023001 (darwin 14.4.0)
Encode:              2.75
Unicode::UTF8:       0.60
PerlIO::encoding:    0.21
PerlIO::utf8_strict: 0.006


ar.txt: Size: 25918 Code points: 14308 (U+0000..U+007F: 2698 U+0080..U+07FF: 11610)
                    Rate :encoding(UTF-8)      Encode :utf8_strict Unicode::UTF8
:encoding(UTF-8)  3058/s               --        -19%         -73%          -87%
Encode            3754/s              23%          --         -67%          -84%
:utf8_strict     11361/s             272%        203%           --          -52%
Unicode::UTF8    23620/s             672%        529%         108%            --


el.txt: Size: 103974 Code points: 58748 (U+0000..U+007F: 13560 U+0080..U+07FF: 45150 U+0800..U+FFFF: 38)
                   Rate :encoding(UTF-8)       Encode :utf8_strict Unicode::UTF8
:encoding(UTF-8)  780/s               --         -19%         -73%          -86%
Encode            958/s              23%           --         -66%          -83%
:utf8_strict     2855/s             266%         198%           --          -48%
Unicode::UTF8    5498/s             605%         474%          93%            --


en.txt: Size: 82171 Code points: 82055 (U+0000..U+007F: 81988 U+0080..U+07FF: 18 U+0800..U+FFFF: 49)
                    Rate :encoding(UTF-8)      Encode :utf8_strict Unicode::UTF8
:encoding(UTF-8)  1111/s               --        -16%         -90%          -96%
Encode            1327/s              19%          --         -88%          -95%
:utf8_strict     11446/s             931%        763%           --          -60%
Unicode::UTF8    28635/s            2478%       2058%         150%            --


ja.txt: Size: 180109 Code points: 64655 (U+0000..U+007F: 6913 U+0080..U+07FF: 30 U+0800..U+FFFF: 57712)
                   Rate :encoding(UTF-8)       Encode :utf8_strict Unicode::UTF8
:encoding(UTF-8)  553/s               --         -27%         -72%          -91%
Encode            757/s              37%           --         -61%          -87%
:utf8_strict     1960/s             254%         159%           --          -67%
Unicode::UTF8    5915/s             970%         682%         202%            --


lv.txt: Size: 138397 Code points: 127160 (U+0000..U+007F: 117031 U+0080..U+07FF: 9021 U+0800..U+FFFF: 1108)
                   Rate :encoding(UTF-8)       Encode :utf8_strict Unicode::UTF8
:encoding(UTF-8)  605/s               --         -19%         -80%          -91%
Encode            746/s              23%           --         -75%          -88%
:utf8_strict     3043/s             403%         308%           --          -53%
Unicode::UTF8    6453/s             967%         765%         112%            --


ru.txt: Size: 151633 Code points: 85266 (U+0000..U+007F: 19263 U+0080..U+07FF: 65639 U+0800..U+FFFF: 364)
                   Rate :encoding(UTF-8)       Encode :utf8_strict Unicode::UTF8
:encoding(UTF-8)  542/s               --         -19%         -73%          -86%
Encode            673/s              24%           --         -66%          -83%
:utf8_strict     2001/s             269%         197%           --          -50%
Unicode::UTF8    4010/s             640%         496%         100%            --


sv.txt: Size: 96449 Code points: 92894 (U+0000..U+007F: 89510 U+0080..U+07FF: 3213 U+0800..U+FFFF: 171)
                    Rate :encoding(UTF-8)      Encode :utf8_strict Unicode::UTF8
:encoding(UTF-8)   923/s               --        -17%         -85%          -93%
Encode            1109/s              20%          --         -82%          -92%
:utf8_strict      5998/s             550%        441%           --          -56%
Unicode::UTF8    13604/s            1374%       1127%         127%            --


zh.txt: Size: 62891 Code points: 24519 (U+0000..U+007F: 5317 U+0080..U+07FF: 32 U+0800..U+FFFF: 19170)
                    Rate :encoding(UTF-8)      Encode :utf8_strict Unicode::UTF8
:encoding(UTF-8)  1630/s               --        -23%         -75%          -87%
Encode            2104/s              29%          --         -68%          -83%
:utf8_strict      6549/s             302%        211%           --          -48%
Unicode::UTF8    12630/s             675%        500%          93%            --
```

Comment: Just `use warnings qw(FATAL utf8)` and the regular `:utf8` layer is perfectly fine. You may also want to separately control subwarnings `surrogate`, `non_unicode`, `nonchar` — something that’s not even possible when using the slow module.

Comment: @tchrist, it's not, the subwarnings only apply on output, on input using readline() they have no effect. The utf8 encoding for accepts ill-formed UTF-8, such as encoded surrogates. Try this: `$ perl -E 'open my $fh, "<:utf8", \"\xED\xB0\x80" or die; printf "U+%.4X\n", ord readline($fh)'`, it's completely silent and an encoded U+DC00 is ill-formed by the Unicode standard.

Comment: @tchrist, BTW, [Unicode::UTF8](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::UTF8) isn't slow and implements support for all subwarnings `surrogate`, `non_unicode` and `nonchar`.

Comment: Your numbers are impressive. For what it’s worth, I meant  `:encoding(UTF-8)` which is notoriously slow and also unresponsive to subwarnings.